# Wrong number of arguments when calling super

Tags: ruby

```
class A
  def initialize
    print "Hello! "
  end
end

class B <  A
  def initialize(name)
    super
    print "My name is #{name}!"
  end
end

test = B.new("Fred")
```

And I get

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

But why? Class `B` requires one argument, and I am giving it all right. Class `A` doesn't require any argument, so I am not passing anything through `super` at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use super() in order to call it with no arguments. Super by itself automatically calls the parent with the arguments provided to itself (ie. "Name")